# trying to unmarshal aws codepipeline result

Tags: go, aws-sdk-go

I am very new at Golang AWS SDK V2, I had similar code work without AWS results, but this one is getting me issues since the types are different. Also, I have search and none of the examples is with the code pipeline aws-sdk-v2 with the type of JSON I have to unmarshal.

I hope some of you can help me.

— This below is main.go I have the structs in another file called un-marshal.go that I created with the result of getting the same output I need from awscli tool and passing it by https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "encoding/json"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/codepipeline"
    
)

func main() {

    pipeline_name := "frontend"

    // Load the Shared AWS Configuration (~/.aws/config)
    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(), config.WithRegion("eu-central-1"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to load SDK config, %v", err)
    }

    client := codepipeline.NewFromConfig(cfg)

    pipeJson, err := client.GetPipelineState(context.TODO(), &codepipeline.GetPipelineStateInput{
        Name: &pipeline_name,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error getting Pipeline")
    }

    var cookie PipeLineResult

    json.Unmarshal(pipeJson, &cookie)

    fmt.Println("The name of the pipeline is: %s",cookie.PipelineName)
    
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
/main.go:39:17: cannot use pipeJson (variable of type *codepipeline.GetPipelineStateOutput) as type []byte in argument to json.Unmarshal
```

Here I am lost because it is a new type, and not sure if I should convert, how to convert or work with the native type etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `pipeJson` is likely to be a struct, not some JSON input which you need to unmarshal.

Comment: Hello, what do you mean? The response from AWS is in JSON format, I have it in front of me. I created the structs, so I can marshal into them as in Structured Data. like I can get the same info I need with awscli, but I want to do the same with GO so later on I can convert into a lambda funtion. But maybe because is using the aws-sdk-go v2 is actually resolving already to a struct? This is what you mean? If so, I can just call it as a regular struct?  a bit confused.  and thank btw

Comment: pipeJson is already a struct. Check aws sdk docs